# insert query is giving no error but is not inserting in the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a  insert query which i m using to insert data into SQL Server DB 2008 using c#.net code. the query does not give any error but also does not insert data into DB
Following is the code :-

```
string strcon = connection();

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.ConnectionString = strcon;
    con.Open();
    strquery = query + " values( '"+ cheqval +"' , '" +
        dtval.ToShortDateString() +"' , '"+ amtval +"','"+ conameval + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

my insert query is forming correctly but is not inserting data into the DB.
What shud i do .... please help .... i also tried the parameterised query but even that does not work :((

Comment: When you step through the code, is the part inside of the `if` statement being executed?  Also, what is the value of `query` before this piece of code begins?

Comment: Please indent all of your code at least 4 spaces so that it will be formatted correctly.  Also, please add the text of the "strquery" variable.

Comment: Could one value be NULL?  Which when you NULL + a string = NULL?  I would step through your code to see what strquery's value is at the SqlCommand declaration.

Comment: You also may want to see if there's something else with an open transaction on the table.

Comment: Please post the query it sends by grabbing it in profiler.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is to see if the table has a trigger. An instead of trigger could be overruling your insert. The comments about checking to see if you are hitting the inside of the IF or that one value being null making the code workout incorrectly are also things to check.

Comment: I was just looking at the same issue this morning and was stumped until I read this! It was a trigger of course... Thanks!

Comment: query = "insert into dbo.income2" (dbo is the name of the schema) and strquery = "insert into dbo.income2 values ('ASWQ5673' , '04-04-2012' , '50000','aus')".I have cheked everything nothing is NULL and there is no trigger on the table as well or a open transaction on the table.Thanks all for the comments ... pls help me to proceed further.I have also checked by hard-coding the insert query still there is no insertion of data in the DB.